# If $\ker(f) \neq \{0\}$, then $f(G)$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $15$ and $H$ is any group. Show that if $f:G \to H$ is a homomorphism with a non-trivial kernel (i.e. $\ker(f) \neq \{0\}$), then $f(G)$ is abelian).

If $f$ is a homomorphism then for $x,y \in G$ we have $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. We need to show that $f(x)f(y)=f(y)f(x)$.

How will I prove this?

Comment: Is it necessary the kernel be nontrivial? It seems to me that the only group of order $15$ is cyclic, so not only is $f(G)$ abelian, but it is cyclic, too.

Comment: How do I know that there is only one group of order 15. I know that groups of prime orders only have one group which is the cyclic group.

Comment: You might not have it in your class, but it follows from Sylow theory. The group $G$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, which in turn, is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes we have cover that. But I so not think that it is enough to claim that since there is one group of order 15 that cyclic then f is abelian

Comment: @Clayton : Kernel being nontrivial is necessary if the OP can not use the fact that any group of order $15$ is cyclic or something similar....

Comment: @Praphulka: of course, that is why I mentioned the possibility Sylow theory hadn't been covered. Still a fact the OP might find interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Isomorphism Theorem :

$$G/Ker(f)\cong f(G)$$

What are possible orders of $Ker(f)$???

Comment: The possible orders of the kernel are 1,3,5 and 15.

Comment: No... Kernel is non trivial so its order can not be $1$.... For other possibilities what can you say about order of $G/Ker(f)$??

Comment: The order of $G /Ker(f)$ is 3,5,1

Comment: In any case the group is of prime order... see?? any group of prime order is ____ ??

Comment: Any group of prime order is cyclic. Hence it is abelian. Question: where am I using the fact that f is a homomomrphism?

Comment: When you use the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : When i say $G/Ker(f)\cong f(G)$ there i am using $f$ is a homomorphism..

Comment: @Nishant : That is it.. :)

Comment: Do you have any doubts in this????

Answer (score 1):

1) Do you know there's only one group (up to isomorphism) of order $\;15\;$ ?

2) Do you know the homomorphic image of an abelian group is abelian?

And we're done.